# Process multiple files having huge amount of data through Glue Job Using Pyspark Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a scenario where we have to process 9 files through Glue Job. Currently we are using Pyspark and reading all 9 files into a single dataframe. The size of files is around 11GB and pipeline is going into unlimited time execution and sometimes it fails with "No space left on device" error.
Glue Job details:
Worker Type: G2X(8vCPU, 32GB RAM)
Number of workers: Increased till 200.
I would like to know is there any way to process the files effectively

Comment: Something not right here. It doesn't take 200 nodes to read just 11GB of data, that's not a lot of data. Can you share your code?

Comment: At least describe the transformation you apply on the dataframe and the expected end-result.